# これで決定 vs これに決めた

Tags: meaning, particles

Having figured out what to do, the protagonist says「これで決定」. Later, having picked one option out of several, she says 「これに決めた」.

What's the difference in the meaning between these, and why are the particles different (で / に)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think these two これs are referring to different things.

In **これで**決定, これ is referring to the current situation (i.e. what just happened) so a translation would be "and with this/because of this, I have decided".  This これ is not talking about **what** was decided. [See this link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25698/what-is-the-%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A7-in-%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A7%E5%A4%B1%E7%A4%BC%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99).

In これ**に**決めた, これ **is** talking about what was decided. "I decided **on** this".

Comment: And the two verbs are interchangeable in these two examples?

Comment: @max Grammatically, yes. I would guess that 決定する, being a する verb is a bit more stiff/formal but I may be wrong.